# Keep getting segmentation fault (core dumped) in C programming and I am trying to pass a 2d array

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, computer-science

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

double **transpose(double **arr, int r, int c);

double **transpose(double **arr, int r, int c){
                //will hold the transposed matrix
                double **arrT;
                arrT = (double **)malloc(c * sizeof(double *));
        for(int i = 0; i < c; i++){
                                arrT[i] = (double *)malloc(r * sizeof(double));
                }

        //transpose the matrix
        for(int i = 0; i < c; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < r; j++){
                        arrT[j][i] = arr[i][j];
                }
        }

        return arrT;


}




int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
        

        //if there is no argument
        if(argc < 2){
            printf("There is no argument\n");
            return -1;


        }

          //training data
                char *fname = argv[1];

                //test data
                char *fname2 = argv[2];

                //pointer for training data
                FILE *fptr;

                //pointer for test data
            FILE *fptr2;

        //number of columns
                int column;

                //number of rows
                int row;

                //opens training data file and reads it
                fptr = fopen(fname, "r");
        
         //will scan the first line of training data
                //to store column of attributes and we add
                //1 more column for price
                fscanf(fptr, "%d\n", &column);
                //adds column for prices
                column++;


         printf("Number of columns: %d\n", column);

                //will scan the second line of training data
                //to store number of rows
                fscanf(fptr, "%d\n", &row);

         printf("Number of rows: %d\n", row);

        

        //allocate array X that will hold attributes
        double **X;
        X = (double **)malloc(row * sizeof(double *));
        
        //allocate array that will hold everything attributes
        //and prices
        double **arr;
        arr = (double **)malloc(row * sizeof(double *));

        //allocate array that will hold prices
        double *Y;
        Y = (double *)malloc(row * sizeof(double *));
        for(int i = 0; i < row; i++){
            X[i] = (double *)malloc(column * sizeof(double));
            arr[i] = (double *)malloc(column * sizeof(double));
        }
        
        //will store the whole training data into arr
        printf("This is training data: \n");
        for(int i = 0; i < row; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < column; j++){
                fscanf(fptr, "%lf,", &arr[i][j]);
                printf("%lf\t", arr[i][j]); 
            }
            printf("\n");

        }
        
        //copies training data for the attribute array
        for(int i = 0; i < row; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < column; j++){
                X[i][j] = arr[i][j];
            }
        
        }
        
        
         //will set attributes first column
                //to all 1's
                for(int i = 0; i < row; i++){
                        X[i][0] = 1;
                }
        
        printf("This is attributes:\n");
         for(int i = 0; i < row; i++){
                        for(int j = 0; j < column; j++){
                                printf("%lf\t", X[i][j]);
                        }
            printf("\n");
                        
                }

         //will set the first column or training
         //data to the prices array
         printf("This is prices: \n");
         for(int i = 0; i < row; i++){
            Y[i] = arr[i][0];
            printf("%lf\n", Y[i]);
         }
        
         //matrix will hold transposed
         double **trans;
        
        transpose(X, row, column);
/*
         printf("This is transposed of attributes\n");
         for(int i = 0; i < row; i++){
                        for(int j = 0; j < column; j++){
                                printf("%lf\t", trans[i][j]);
                        }
                        printf("\n");

                }


*/
        return 0;
    }


double **transpose(double **arr, int r, int c){
                //will hold the transposed matrix
                double **arrT;
                arrT = (double **)malloc(c * sizeof(double *));
        for(int i = 0; i < c; i++){
                                arrT[i] = (double *)malloc(r * sizeof(double));
                }

        //transpose the matrix
        for(int i = 0; i < c; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < r; j++){
                        arrT[j][i] = arr[i][j];
                }
        }

        return arrT;


}
```

Hi so i havent completed the code yet but the code should still run fine as it is. The problem is though I try to the method to transpose the matrix and when it does it says segmentation fault core dumped. If you can tell me whats wrong that would be greatly appreciated. I am trying to pass a 2d array.

The txt file it should read should be input.txt:
where 4 is the first line, and 10 is the second line.

```
4
10
221900,3,1,1180,1955
538000,3,2.25,2570,1951
180000,2,1,770,1933
604000,4,3,1960,1965
510000,3,2,1680,1987
1230000,4,4.5,5420,2001
257500,3,2.25,1715,1995
291850,3,1.5,1060,1963
229500,3,1,1780,1960
323000,3,2.5,1890,2003
```

Comment: I assume you didn't mean to paste your implementation of `transpose` twice.

Comment: Your code will only work on square matrices.  If `rows` and `columns` are not the same, then you will be indexing out of bounds and will invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: Even for square matrices, your transpose logic won't work (just run some values through it by hand to convince yourself - try a 2x2 matrix).  But in the square matrix case, your results will be wrong, but the behavior will not be undefined.

Comment: The only array in your entire code is `char *argv[]`.

Comment: In C, there is no need to cast the return of `malloc`, it is unnecessary. See: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714)

Comment: //transpose the matrix
        for(int i = 0; i < c; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < r; j++){
                        arrT[i][j] = arr[j][i];
                }
        }
This will limit the number of transposed rows to the number of columns.  And yes, you will lose data because as others have pointed out, the number of rows has to equal the number of columns.